# jquery submit form and then show results in an existing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple one text input form that when submitted, needs to fetch a php file (passing the inputs to the file) and then take the result (just a line of text) and place it in a `div` and fade that `div` into view.

Here is what I have now:

```
<form id=create method=POST action=create.php>
<input type=text name=url>
<input type="submit" value="Create" /> 

<div id=created></div>
```

What I need is the results of `create.php?url=INPUT`, to be dynamically loaded into the `div` called `created`.

I have the jquery form script, but I haven't been able to get it to work right. But I do have the library loaded (the file).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This code should do it. You don't need the Form plugin for something as simple as this:

```
$('#create').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('#created').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
```

Comment: And since he wants : create.php?url=INPUT - he should set the form method to "GET"

Comment: I think that was just him describing the data that should be sent. The form's method says POST, so I'm assuming he wants that.

Comment: **God like!!!** Exactly what I was looking for. For such a simple question that users see on any number of sites every day there is very little documentation/examples on the web about.

Comment: I love how you included the way to use the form method, action and url.  Most people would have just given an example by hardcoding those values...

Comment: This just saved my butt. Also, if you have text ABOVE the form that you need replaced, just stick the text at the top of the form, just INSIDE the <form> tag. It should render the same unless there's some weird css thing controlling text inside the form.

Comment: To get this to work you have to call `$('#create').submit();` after the above code to trigger it. `$('#create').submit()` is a shortcut for `.on(submit, ...`.

Answer (score 7):

This works also for file upload

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var url=$(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status)
        {
            $('#created').html(data); //content loads here

        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {
            console.log("error");

        }
    });        

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use AJAX to post the form if you don't want the page to be refreshed.

```
$('#create').submit(function () {
    $.post('create.php', $('#create').serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
         $('#created').append(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Catching a submit button's click event is not the proper event to catch for a form submission. you want to catch the form's submit event.

Comment: I tried this, but it is taking me to the create.php page when i click submit.

Comment: the `return false;` should prevent that I believe.