# Ajax display results in already created div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have index.php like main page and I have sidebar.php included in index.php. In index.php I have div `id=content` with some content already loaded.. and in sidebar.php a I have

```
<form id="search" method="post" action="" >
      <input type="search" name="search" id="search"> 
      <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" class="btnButton" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

so how can I display my search result in div `id=content` when I click on submit?

Comment: an `id` must be **uniq**

Comment: This might interest you: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery submit form and then show results in an existing div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218245/jquery-submit-form-and-then-show-results-in-an-existing-div)

Comment: Search is related to server-side, how can html solve the issue?

Comment: please add more explanation, this seams an AJAX task...

Comment: i have index.php and in index.php i have <div id="content"> where i have some images loaded from databse.In index.php i include sidebar.php and also i have php code that display results(i dont know where to put it)In sidebar.php i have this form for search,and when i click on submit that is in sidebar.php i want to change <div id=content>in index.php with results from search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the search.php from main page using Jquery ajax. make sure u reference the jQuery library.

```
//Main Page
<form id="search" method="post" action="" >
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search"> 
      <input type="submit" name="search1" id="search1" class="btnButton" value="Search"/>
</form> 

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //jquery click event
    $("#search").live("click", function(e){

       //disable default form submit postpage
       e.preventDefault();

       //make ajax call to the search.php parsing the search textbox value as query string
       $.get("search.php?s="+$("#search").val(), function(result){

            //Result will be dumped in the div
            $("#content").html(result);

       });

   });

});

</script>



//Search PHP Script search.php
<?php

//Get the search String
$string = $_GET["s"];

//DO search query and echo it on this page.
?>
```

Comment: tnx Nwafor..this is good and simple :)

Comment: `id`s are still duplicates. You should use an increment like `<input id="search_01"> <input id="search_02">`

Answer (score 1):

You only have to select from jquery the element and then execute the method .ajax{}

For example

```
$('#contentElementId').ajax({options...})
```

the result loads on the

```
<div id="contentElementId"></div>
```