# Catching submit for generated form, so that users will see the processed result in a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, bind, document-ready

User clicks on a menu, and  using the following code, the menu `$.load()`s it's linked content:

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu a').click(function() {
        $('#content').load(this.href);  
        return false;
    });
});
```

OK, now the form's loaded. There is still a problem. When the forms is submitted, the result shouldn't bring us to the real `action` address. So I'm using the following code:

```
$('#content').on('submit', function() { // catch the form's submit event
    alert('begin');
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            alert('aaaa');
            $('#content').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
```

Unfortunately `on` is not called and `alert('begin');` doesn't work!

Thanks to [jquery submit form and then show results in an existing div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218245/jquery-submit-form-and-then-show-results-in-an-existing-div)

Comment: have you tried : $('#content').on('submit','form', function() {

Comment: @jbl No, thank you. I will

Comment: @jbl No luck unfortunately. Thank you anyway `:)`

Comment: please post relevant parts of the markup resulting from the load() call.

Comment: There is not anything special. In fact it's a `<div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div>` that will be changed everytime a new menu item is clicked (because of the `load` explained in the first code I wrote)

Comment: the point is we can't help you if we don't see at least the markup with form tag. My first comment should work provided #content contains the form.

Answer (score 0):

I had entered the first peace of code, not in `$(document).ready(function() {});` and it is working so perfect, but the second code didn't work without the document ready.

**But Why?** I don't know.

The final code that works now is the one below:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#content').on('submit', 'form', function() { // catch the form's submit event
        alert('begin');
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                $('#content').html(response); // update the DIV
            }
        });
        return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
    }); 

});
```

Thank you guys for your try.

Comment: "But Why? I don't know." I guess that is because this script is located before the html markup for div#content. It is the point of the .ready(). It seems there were two problems with the code (this wouldn't work without the on(...'form'...)

Comment: @jbl Yes, you are right. It doesn't work without passing `'form'` as the second parameter. Also thank you for your speech about `$(document).ready()`